# assign a id value to a variable in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, element

I i have the following code that outputs long / lat on my page however i am wanting to assign it to a variable so i can then pass the value by appending it to the url as in page.html?cords=[varname]

the code i am working with currently that displays the corodinates is

```
s+= "<li><a href='petcareservices.html?coords=' id='geolocation'></a></li>";
```

currently the actual co ords are displaying as the text value of the button but i need to pass them as the value attached to coords=

trust the above makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var coordsVar = "yourValue";
s += "<li><a href='petcareservices.html?coords="+coordsVar+"' id='geolocation'></a></li>";
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Hi Jcamera  thanks for your reply6  i am not sure if i made myself clear the value is contained in the geolocation id id=geolocation so i am needing to get the value contained within the 'geolocation' assigned to the var. The geolocation is dynamically determined by a geolocation function code